# Create bar chart with database values using JFreeChart

Tags: java, swing, jfreechart, bar-chart

I am fetching values from my database which has two columns. I wanted to create a bar chart on click of a button and display the bar chart in a panel. How do I do it using JFreeChart? I'm using mysql database.

Comment: Please take a loot at the [samples of JFreeChart](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/samples.html) and their [documentation](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/index.html) to get a feel of how it works. Also, can you show us what you tried yourself? Where's your code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved my problem. Just had to read a little about `JFreechart`. Here's the solution :

```
    String toc = "";
    int summary = 0;
    try {
        DefaultCategoryDataset dataset = new DefaultCategoryDataset();
        Class.forName(JDBC_DRIVER);

        con = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);

        String query = "Select toc as TypeOfCall,Sum(toc) as SummaryOfCalls from processeddata_table group by toc";

        ps = con.prepareStatement(query);
        rs = ps.executeQuery();
        while (rs.next()) {
            toc = rs.getString("TypeOfCall");
            summary = rs.getInt("SummaryOfCalls");
            dataset.setValue(summary, toc, toc);
        }
        JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createBarChart("Call cost", "TypeOfCall", "SummaryOfCalls", dataset, PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, false, true, false);
        CategoryPlot p = chart.getCategoryPlot();

         //p.setRangeGridlinePaint(Color.BLUE);

        ChartPanel panel = new ChartPanel(chart);
        panel.setVisible(true);
        panel.setSize(200, 200);
        display_graph.add(panel);

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {

    }
```